# My site does not display properly

Tags: display

I recently created a website for a company.
The problem is that everyone in the company sees a homepage that does not exist in the current site. (see att.). They tried it on all devices and also to clear the browser cache, but the problem is not solved.
What could be the problem?

[this is the odd page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcYex.png)

Thanks

Comment: Is that URL Correct?

Comment: Doesn't seem a developer question, maybe a DNS configuration issue. Let me point you how to ask a good question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Ask them to `>ping www.carnevali.com`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you have changed the address that your domain points to (IP address of your server), you need to wait several hours for DNS servers to propagate the changes.

For a given address I see something like this:
[image]

Is that your website?